# Search for universal monotoneous function for time-series trend removal

Tags: time-series, trend, test-for-trend

I have some time-series. They may be written as
$$T(n)-T(n-1)=f(n)+\xi,$$ where T(n) - time of $n^{th}$ occurrence,  $f(n)$ some monotonous function from number of event, $\xi$ random noise. These time series may be plotted in a following way:

[image]

I am interested in $\xi$, thus I want to subtract $f(n)$. This function may differs from time-series to time-series. The only knowledge I have - it is monotonous (sign may vary). So, I want to find $f(n)$ just fiting some monotonous curve to data.

**Could you help me and advice some universal class of equations to make such fit?**

*(May be something like Taylor or Fourier series?)*

P.S. More generally speaking, I have some data, which may be well fitted by curves depicted above. The question is to find some class of curves, which will be good approximation to such a heterogenous curves.

Comment: Your equation doesn't quite make sense to me. If you want $T$ to be monotonic in expectation, $f$ should be positive rather than monotonic. If $f$ is monotonic rather than positive, $T$ might not be monotonic (consider $f = -1/x$, which is monotonic increasing).

Comment: I've edit question. I mean f(n). I have quite different trend of between events intervals, but they are monotonous. The picture demonstrates different trend of intervals, after reconstitution of time-series.